# Execute cpp/exe from TCL

Tags: gcc, tcl

I would lo call call_c_code cpp/exe from TCL.
I have tried the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
set scripts_path call_c_code.exe
exec gcc -c $scripts_path >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

But I have the following error:

```
% source "tcl_to_call_C.tcl"
gcc.exe: warning: call_c_code.exe: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

The call_c_code.exe is a basic HelloWorld:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("Hello World!");
   return 0;
}
```

Is that the right way to call the ".exe" from TCL?

Comment: This is rather strange.  You normally call gcc passing it a source code file (e.g. something.cpp) from which to create an executable (e.g. something.exe).  You seem to be passing a source code file with a .exe extension, which indicates to gcc that it's already compiled code, so gcc thinks it has no work to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing

> ```
>  set scripts_path call_c_code.exe
>  exec gcc -c $scripts_path >@stdout 2>@stderr
> ```

you do

```
gcc -c call_c_code.exe
```

which is wrong, you need to indicate the source file to compile it

so may be something like

```
gcc -c call_c_code.c
```

then

```
 set scripts_path call_c_code.c
 exec gcc -c $scripts_path >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

but using the option `-c` you just produce the object but not the executable, may be you want

```
 set scripts_path call_c_code.c
 exec gcc  $scripts_path >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

if you really want the extension *exe* even out of Windows add the option `-o`

```
 set scripts_path call_c_code
 exec gcc -o $scripts_path.exe $scripts_path.c >@stdout 2>@stderr
```

anyway to hide the possible messages produced by the compiler is not a good idea, it is must better to remove the redirections, and on the contrary add the option `-Wall` to ask the compiler to signal more

Comment: The compiler looks at extensions when deciding what to do with a file. You _have_ to get them right.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a C compiler is a little trickier than you're used to. You need to put your source code in a file with the extension `.c`, then compile it to an executable (extension `.exe` *on Windows;* other platforms have different rules!), and only then can you run it. And there's a *lot* more other complexities too when you start using libraries. But first…

1. Rename the file of source code from `call_c_code.exe` to `call_c_code.c`.
2. Rewrite your compile-and-run code:

   ```
   set Compiler "gcc"; # Can override this to be clang if you have it?

   proc compile {sourceFile} {
       global Compiler

       # Make sure we use the full name of the executable when running it
       set executable [file normalize [file rootname $sourceFile].exe]
       # Only run the compiler if file not executable or source file is newer
       if {
           ![file isfile $executable]
           || ![file executable $executable]
           || [file mtime $sourceFile] > [file mtime $executable]
       } then {   # <<< I like to use 'then' after a multi-line condition!
           exec $Compiler -c -o $executable $sourceFile >@stdout 2>@stderr
       }
       return $executable
   }

   set exe [compile call_c_code.c]
   set output [exec $exe]
   puts "The output was: $output"
   ```

Comment: It's possible to use MSVC to build too, but the flags you pass are different and I don't know them well enough to write the code blind. ;)